# RTK Query: Transform all query responses at once

Tags: redux, react-redux, rtk-query

With RTK Query, the response of an endpoint can be transformed with [`transformResponse`](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#transforming-responses) like so:

```js
import { apiSlice } from '../api/apiSlice'
const usersAdapter = createEntityAdapter()
const initialState = usersAdapter.getInitialState()

import { camelizeKeys } from 'humps'

export const extendedApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: () => '/users',
      transformResponse: (response) =>  camelizeKeys(response.data),
    }),
    // … 25 other endpoints
  })
})
```

If each endpoints response need to be transformed in a certain way, say for example by humps `camelizeKeys` function, this becomes very repetitive rather quickly.

What is the recommended way/best practice, to (globally) define a `transformResponse` for all queryies (and ideally another one for all mutations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the best place to define such a global transformation is in custom `baseQuery`:

```
export const baseQueryWithCamelize: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions = {}) => {
  const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
  if (result.data) {
    result.data = camelizeKeys(result.data as any);
  }
  return result;
};
```

then you should use it in root `api` def:

```
export default createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithCamelize,
  tagTypes: TAGS,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
      healthcheck: builder.query<void, void>({
      query: () => URLS.HEALTHCHECK,
    }),
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is for anyone who is not using typescript.**

`changeResponse` is the function you use to change the response for all the endpoints, it should return whatever you want i.e an Array or an Object.

```js
import {changeResponse} from "../functions/changeResponse"

const baseQueryWithChange = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    if (result.data) {
        result.data = changeResponse(result.data.data) // function used to transform global response
    }
    return result
}
```

wrap `baseQuery` with the `baseQueryWithChange` function.

```js
export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithChange,
    endpoints: builder => ({})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `responseHandler` in `fetchBaseQuery`

```
const customFetchBaseQuery = ({ ...props }:FetchBaseQueryArgs) => fetchBaseQuery({
      ...props,
      responseHandler: (response) => {
        camelizeKeys(response.data)
      },
    });
```

and use in `createApi`

```
export const userApi = createApi({
 //...
  baseQuery: customFetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
///...
```