# How to use transformResponse in RTK Query to change server response

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, react-redux, react-query

Please I am new to RTK query, I made an API call that returns an array of arrays of objects, I want to use the **transformResponse** option to flatten the API response to just one array of objects.

Here is my code

```js
getStocks: builder.query({
    query: credentials => ({
        url: `stocks`,
        body: {credentials},
        transform: response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        },
    }),
   })
```

Here is the API response data

```js
[
    [
        {
            1. Information: "Monthly Adjusted Prices and Volumes"
            2. Symbol: "AAPL"
            3. Last Refreshed: "2022-06-28 16:00:01"
            4. Time Zone: "US/Eastern"
        }, 
        {
            1. open: "101.0000"
            2. high: "118.0000"
            3. low: "91.0600"
            4. close: "102.8100"
            5. adjusted close: "0.7848"
            6. volume: "84091200"
            7. dividend amount: "0.0000"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            1. Information: "Monthly Adjusted Prices and Volumes"
            2. Symbol: "MSFT"
            3. Last Refreshed: "2022-06-28 16:00:01"
            4. Time Zone: "US/Eastern"
        }, 
        {
            1. open: "101.0000"
            2. high: "118.0000"
            3. low: "91.0600"
            4. close: "102.8100"
            5. adjusted close: "0.7848"
            6. volume: "84091200"
            7. dividend amount: "0.0000"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            1. Information: "Monthly Adjusted Prices and Volumes"
            2. Symbol: "BYD"
            3. Last Refreshed: "2022-06-28 16:00:01"
            4. Time Zone: "US/Eastern"
        }, 
        {
            1. open: "101.0000"
            2. high: "118.0000"
            3. low: "91.0600"
            4. close: "102.8100"
            5. adjusted close: "0.7848"
            6. volume: "84091200"
            7. dividend amount: "0.0000"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            1. Information: "Monthly Adjusted Prices and Volumes"
            2. Symbol: "SEC"
            3. Last Refreshed: "2022-06-28 16:00:01"
            4. Time Zone: "US/Eastern"
        }, 
        {
            1. open: "101.0000"
            2. high: "118.0000"
            3. low: "91.0600"
            4. close: "102.8100"
            5. adjusted close: "0.7848"
            6. volume: "84091200"
            7. dividend amount: "0.0000"
        }
    ]
]
```

Here is how I want to output the data.

| Symbo | Close |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | 120 |
| BYD | 130 |
| CSC | 123 |
| SEC | 433 |

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71503552/rtk-query-transform-all-query-responses-at-once) where I got the understanding to fabricate my own solution.

I created a custom `baseQueryWithChange` function to (globally) define a transformResponse for all queries and I wrap `baseQuery` with the custom `baseQueryWithChange`

**function to transform API response**

```js
export const changeResponse = async (list) => {
    const dataArray = list.data
    console.log(dataArray) // 10 elements
    
    const finalArray = await dataArray.filter((each) => each.length !== 1) // 6 elements

    const normalizeData = (data) => {
        return data.flatMap((d) => {
            return { ...d[0], ...d[1] };
        });
    };

    const latestList = normalizeData(finalArray)

    console.log(normalizeData(finalArray)); // 6 elements

    return latestList
}
```

**baseQuery**

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
// import function to transform API response
import { changeResponse } from "../../constants/changeResponse";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3500"
})

const baseQueryWithChange = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    if (result.data) {
        result.data = changeResponse(result.data)
        console.log(result.data)
    }
    return result
}

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithChange,
    endpoints: builder => ({})
})
```